# Updating array within array redux

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I've got state with a nested array that looks like the following:

```
{
    list: [
        {
        id: '3546f44b-457e-4f87-95f6-c6717830294b',
        title: 'First Nest',
        key: '0',
        children: [
            {
            id: '71f034ea-478b-4f33-9dad-3685dab09171',
            title: 'Second Nest',
            key: '0-0
            children: [
                {
                id: '11d338c6-f222-4701-98d0-3e3572009d8f',
                title: 'Q. Third Nest',
                key: '0-0-0',
                }
            ],
            }
        ],
    ],
    selectedItemKey: '0'
}
```

Where the goal of the nested array is to mimic a tree and the selectedItemKey/key is how to access the tree node quickly.

I wrote code to update the title of a nested item with the following logic:

```
let list = [...state.list];
let keyArr = state.selectedItemKey.split('-');
let idx = keyArr.shift();
let currItemArr = list;

while (keyArr.length > 0) {
  currItemArr = currItemArr[idx].children;
  idx = keyArr.shift();
}

currItemArr[idx] = {
  ...currItemArr[idx],
  title: action.payload
};

return {
  ...state,
  list
};
```

Things work properly for the first nested item, but for the second and third level nesting, I get the following Immer console errors

```
An immer producer returned a new value *and* modified its draft.
Either return a new value *or* modify the draft.
```

I feel like I'm messing up something pretty big here in regards to my nested array access/update logic, or in the way I'm trying to make a new copy of the state.list and modifying that. Please note the nested level is dynamic, and I do not know the depth of it prior to modifying it.

Thanks again in advance!

Comment: You should modify the `list` property and not return anything.  Immer allows you to modify the state or return a new state but not both at once.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I see! Thank you so much for responding!

Comment: I'm writing an answer for you :) You can return a new state if there is no mutation but there's actually a mutation here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immer allows you to modify the existing draft `state` OR `return` a new state, but not both at once.

It looks like you are trying to return a new state, which is ok so long as there is no mutation.  However you make a modification when you assign `currItemArr[idx] =` . This is a mutation because the elements of `list` and `currItemArr` are the same elements as in `state.list`.  It is a "shallow copy".

But you don't need to worry about shallow copies and mutations because the easier approach is to just modify the draft state and not return anything.

You just need to find the correct object and set its `title` property.  I came up with a shorter way to do that using `array.reduce()`.

```
const keyArr = state.selectedItemKey.split("-");

const target = keyArr.reduce(
  (accumulator, idx) => accumulator.children[idx],
  { children: state.list }
);

target.title = action.payload;
```

Comment: Even better! Thanks for the clarity around my issue and for sharing an even simpler solution! Much thanks, Linda!